# OMA DM features supported in ANDROID APIs?

Tags: android, oma-dm

I would like to know if OMA DM features are supported in Android APIs; well, I have seen that reading certain values from Settings.Secure is possible, but writing is not. I am interested in changing the email,APN,WAP,and mms Settings remotely without displaying the interference to users... Any APIs are available for removing ,listing,and installing applications? Same thing for locking the phone and wiping its content.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

So the answer is operators and manufacturers now have some OMA DM clients that are used to push service parameters and firmwares to devices. But they are not open to external app developers for obvious reasons.

Comment: Could you please specify those obvious reasons?

Comment: So unfortunately operators are slow or they would have commercialized SMSes as a mechanism of Push Notifications. Similarly for OMA DM, the thought is generally to control firmware pushes and push service parameters very particular to operator applications only. I don't know of any operators even thinking of opening up their OMA DM platforms to push parameters from external. If you do please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found several solutions from Sybase(Afaria), InnoPath and RedBand which provide seems full OMA-DM implementation, alongside it seems these solutions only for manufacturers and operators because they need to be bundled into firmware.

Comment: Just because I stumbled across the same question. Mobile phone manufacturer often list on there Website if they offer OMA DM support or not. For example for the [Galaxy Note](http://www.samsung.com/levant/consumer/mobile-phones/mobile-phones/galaxy-note/GT-N7000ZBADAM-spec) or [Motorola BRAVO](http://mediacenter.motorola.com/Fact-Sheets/Motorola-BRAVO-Fact-Sheet-343b.aspx).